# Добавление данных полученных из WPForms в таблицу Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

мне необходимо решить следующую задачу:добавить данные ,введённые пользователем на сайте Wordpress,в определённую таблицу Wordpress.Как будет выглядеть код php для выполнения этой цели и в какой файл необходимо этот код вписывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> мне необходимо решить следующую задачу:добавить данные ,введённые
> пользователем на сайте Wordpress,в определённую таблицу Wordpress.

Для указного плагина есть расширение. Напр https://wordpress.org/plugins/database-for-wpforms/

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался,уже работаю

Comment: @ЖеняМедяник если ответ помог - стоит отметить его решённым.

Comment: Если что, то данный ф-ционал в платной версии плагина

Answer (score 0):

Прежде всего, нужно установить соединение с базой данных. После этого мы можем продолжить с SQL запросом на добавление записи в таблицу MySQL – INSERT. Здесь полный пример кода с подключением и методом вставки:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "base";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
echo "Connected successfully";
 
$sql = "INSERT INTO Students (name, lastname, email) VALUES ('Vasya', 'Peskov', 'vasya@mail.com')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: В вопросе сказано, что данные вводятся пользователем, значит надо добавлять защиту от SQL инъекций

Comment: Это не правильное и ОЧЕНЬ плохое решение в контексте использования ВП.